# Remove Inner Border for a Textbox on ValidationError

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to show a red border around a Textbox when a validation error occurs. This works, but there is also a blue border showing inside the red one, which I don't want to be shown. Is there a way to remove this?

Style for the Textbox

```
<Style x:Key="StandardTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5,10,5" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Blau}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Usage in Window:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
     Text="{Binding Path=Location, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                    NotifyOnValidationError=true}" 
 Style="{StaticResource StandardTextbox}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

[image]

Enlargement:

[image]

Comment: That's your border. You set it to blau. Make it transparent when Validation.HasError true. And or change the error template. Take a look at. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152078/wpf-textbox-setting-red-border-on-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're setting `BorderBrush` to `Blau` inside your `Style`. You can remove it if there is any *Validation* error by using `Triggers`. Like,

```
<Style x:Key="StandardTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5,10,5" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Blau}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Well, Thanks. Here I thought, the HasError would override the BorderBrush.